# Magento Products are not visible in category after switching to multisite

Tags: magento

I have recently switched to multisite functionality in magento which is working fine except one thing that I cant view product list in respective category ie. categories are displaying empty. however I can see the products individually but not in category. please let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Is the product assigned to targeted category ? make sure for the category under the Display Settings tab, the Display Mode is set to "Products Only" or "Static blocks and products". If this is set to "Static block only", the products will not display for the category. Also if using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target website

Comment: the category has Products only settings already. there is something else going wrong but dont know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check is, select products from product grid, click on Update Attributes, on the left hand side 'Websites' tab, check the website on which you want to upload products in. Then reindex the category products.

Comment: I did that but its not the issue. here I want to mention that I have created the category when I was using single site.

Comment: Just another possibilities : 1) Check product visibility to catalog 2) check if products are out of stock and OOS product visibility is not allowed from system config.

Comment: And last but not the least, try deleting var/cache folder and refresh again.

Comment: ok thank you so much I had somehow setting as out of stock. by reversing it its working fine.

Comment: @Ren, that was the basic check expected. So I posted you advance checks.